# how to use multiple bootstrap collapse elements dynamically in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this code which contains html along with php, when there are multiple elements in collapse only the first element is working properly because there is id named collapseOne which should change dynamically for each element.

So, the problem is how to change the id dynamically

```
 <div class="accordion">
    <?php foreach ($topics_list->result_array() as $row) { ?>    
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['name'];
        ?></h2>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse ">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <b><h3> Material Link-:<?php
                            echo "<a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>Link</a></h3></b>";
                            echo"<br> <b><h3>Hardness-:";
                            echo $row['hardness'] . "</h3></b>";
                            echo "<br><b><h3>Type-:" . $row['type'] . "</h3></b>";
                            ?>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>            
                        <?php } ?>
</div>
                        </div>            
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment an index on each iteration and include it in the markup output

```
<div class="accordion">
    <?php 
        $i=0;
        foreach ($topics_list->result_array() as $row) {
        $i++;
        ?>    
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" 
                 data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
                 href="#collapse<?=$i?>">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['name'];
        ?></h2>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse<?=$i?>" class="accordion-body collapse ">
                <div class="accordion-inner">
                    <b><h3> Material Link-:<?php
                            echo "<a href='" . $row['link'] . "'>Link</a></h3></b>";
                            echo"<br> <b><h3>Hardness-:";
                            echo $row['hardness'] . "</h3></b>";
                            echo "<br><b><h3>Type-:" . $row['type'] . "</h3></b>";
                            ?>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>            
                        <?php } ?>
</div>
                        </div>            
                    <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...I can use it

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <?PHP
                        $i = 0;
                        while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery)) {     
                        $i++;
                    ?>
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne<?=$i?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">                         
                                <?=$objResult["rela_Name"];?>
                            </a>
                        </h4>     
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseOne<?=$i?>" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?=$objResult["rela_Detail"];?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?PHP
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```