# PHP while loop not ++'ing variable within if statements

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, carousel

statmentI am currently working on a project. I am having issues with making a variable ++ in the loop while nested in if statements. I really do not understand why it's doing what it's doing. Here is my code.

```
                    <?php $i=0;
                     while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php if(get_field('featured_game') && valid_release(get_field('release_date'))):?>
                     <div class="item <?php if($i == 0){echo 'active';}?> row carousel-<?=$i;?>">

                          // do generated html

                            <style>
                                .carousel-<?=$i;?>{
                                    // do generated css
                                }
                           </style>

                     </div>
                            <?php $i++;?>

                        <?php endif?>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </div>
```

My results have 
carousel-
 these spots all having returned 0 despite the loop running. meaning that incrment is not happening.

if I remove the if statement the loop works, as expected. The if statement are just to verify criteria to be true. I do can place the ++ outside of the if statement I get the same results.

Could some please explain what I am missing here? This seems like such a basic problem. I really do not understand why $i will not increment when does meet the criteria and posts the correct info. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the effort.

Comment: it's difficult to see the code with so much html mixed in. consider separating your php code and your html code.

Comment: The two `if`s can be combined into one if with the use of the `&&` operator. `if(get_field('featured_game') && valid_release(get_field('release_date')))`

Comment: @ham-sandwich ... no he means incrementing - sigh

Comment: If it works as expected without the `if` statements, i'm going to hazard a guess your `if` statements are screwy

Comment: @user3791372 I cleaned up the code. Only showing stuff that is directly affected. The if statement checks for true. valid_release() and get_field can only return true or false.

Comment: <?php endif?> see anything missing from that?

Comment: @KaiQing works with out the semi colon though

Comment: Im not saying it doesn't. I'm just commenting about cleanliness. Adopt a uniform standard or drive everyone crazy who has to look at this.

Comment: `while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();` take another look at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was increment properly all along.

My issue turns out to be that bootstraps carousel cycles the the content within the the parent div not the actual div it seems. If I disable it, or look directly at the source, everything is  what it is supposed to be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404148/how-to-use-multiple-bootstrap-collapse-elements-dynamically-in-php/25404284#25404284

Answer (score 2):

I ran this code:

```
<?php $i = 0;
while ($i < 10) : ?>
    <?php if (true): ?>
        <?php if ($i == 0) {
            echo 'active';
        } ?>
        <?= $i; ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and the result was:

```
active 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

so either

```
get_field('featured_game')
```

or

```
valid_release(get_field('release_date'))
```

must be false.

Try

```
var_dump(get_field('featured_game'));
var_dump(valid_release(get_field('release_date')));
```

inside the loop.

Comment: did such returns true within the loop.